# Remove observation with only one variable different

Tags: sorting, duplicates, sas

This might be easy to do but I am finding it difficult to do in SAS.

I want to remove an observation with all variable same but one. I just want to keep one observation than two.

Example

```
DATA auto ;
  INPUT make $  mpg $ rep78 $ weight $ foreign $;
CARDS ;
AMC     22 3 2930 0
AMC     22 3 2930 1
AMC     22 3 2930 0
AMC     22 3 2930 1
Audi    23 5 2830 1
Audi    23 3 2070 1
;
RUN ;
```

In the AMC we have 3 entries with last two matching except in **foreign** where its 0 and 1. Now I want to keep only one of them.

Example is taken from the following website

With the updated example I need to clean AMC while keeping only **one** 1 and **one** 0. Currently it has 4 entries.

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/sort.htm

Comment: I think I understand your question, but I'm not sure what you mean by keeping only one of them. You mean keeping only one out of the three AMCs or keeping one of the last two AMCs?

Comment: I just want to keep one of the two i.e. removing one of the last two AMC. After removal I will be having 2 AMC out of 3.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't the make always have the same foreign/domestic flag?

Comment: Scott. Unfortuantely in this example it isn't. I will post more relevant example also. Considering awesome capability of SAS for munging and manipulating data it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Ok, well then how do you decide which is correct? You may run into data integrity issues by computationally deleting rows based on your sort order rather than the 'correct' row.

Comment: Scott Good point. I am updating the Example.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep one of them that are next to each other, we can `merge` the data set with itself with no `by` statement starting with the 2nd observation. It is likely that there are other ways of doing it (e.g. proc sql), instead of doing it by brute force from the data step.

```
data work.merged;
    merge work.auto
    work.auto(rename=(make=make2 mpg=mpg2 rep78=rep2 weight=weight2
    foreign=foreign2) firstobs=2);

    if make=make2 and mpg=mpg2 and rep78=rep2 and weight=weight2
    and foreign NE foreign2 then delete;

    if make=make2 and mpg=mpg2 and rep78=rep2 and weight NE weight2
    and foreign=foreign2 then delete;

    if make=make2 and mpg=mpg2 and rep78 NE rep2 and weight=weight2
    and foreign=foreign2 then delete;

    if make=make2 and mpg NE mpg2 and rep78=rep2 and weight=weight2
    and foreign=foreign2 then delete;

    if make NE make2 and mpg=mpg2 and rep78=rep2 and weight=weight2
    and foreign=foreign2 then delete;

run; 

proc print data=work.merged;
    var make mpg rep78 weight foreign;
run;
```

In the end we can compare the `merged` variables using conditional statements to determine which ones have all variables the same except one.

Output of proc print w/o var statement:

```
 Obs    make    mpg    rep78    weight    foreign    make2    mpg2    rep2    weight2    foreign2

  1     AMC     22       3       2930        0       AMC       22      3       2930         0
  2     AMC     22       3       2930        1       Audi      23      5       2830         1
  3     Audi    23       5       2830        1       Audi      23      3       2070         1
  4     Audi    23       3       2070        1
```

Comment: For example like this it may work. But in real case I have more than 20 variables and it varies a lot also.

Comment: Ok, I will add another answer with a shorter set of conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your data set has been sorted using `proc sort` such that the observations that have all variables the same except one are right next to each other like in your example.

```
 data work.merged;
    merge work.auto
    work.auto(rename=(make=make2 mpg=mpg2 rep78=rep2 weight=weight2
    foreign=foreign2) firstobs=2);
    x = 0;

    if (make=make2) then x + 1;
    if (mpg=mpg2) then x + 1;
    if (rep78=rep2) then x + 1;
    if (weight=weight2) then x + 1;
    if (foreign=foreign2) then x + 1;
    if x = 4 then delete;
run;
```

Output:

```
    Obs   make   mpg   rep78   weight   foreign   make2   mpg2   rep2   weight2   foreign2   x

     1    AMC    22      3      2930       0      AMC      22     3      2930        0       5
     2    AMC    22      3      2930       1      Audi     23     5      2830        1       1
     3    Audi   23      5      2830       1      Audi     23     3      2070        1       3
     4    Audi   23      3      2070       1                                                 0
```

We will compare the `merged` variables and if they are the same we will increment `x` by 1. In this case, we can increment variable `x` from 0 up to a maximum of 5 every time. Since there are 5 variables in this data set, x = 5 is the maximum and x = 0 is minimum. If all of them are the same except one, then x = 4. In the case of x = 4, we can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

From your updated example, I think what you want is all the distinct rows in your dataset. This can be done using either a data step or proc sql:

```
PROC SORT DATA=auto OUT=auto2 NODUPLICATES ;
  BY _all_ ;
RUN ;
```

`NODUPLICATES` removes any duplicate rows, `_all_` specifies for it to check all fields in the dataset.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table auto2 as
    select distinct *
    from auto
    ;
quit;
```

`*` is a wildcard to specify all columns in the dataset and distinct removes duplicate rows